# Difference between "so", "very", "extremely" and "really"

Tags: differences, so-vs-very

What is the difference between *so*, *very*, *extremely* and *really*? For example,

> We're **so/very/extremely/really** glad you could come!

Answer (score 4):

Here *so* is an extra amplifier and can be used with or without one of the others, as in "We're so very glad you came".

The others have different literal meanings: a high level of gladness; a maximum level of gladness; and a truthful level of gladness.  But in practice the effect of each is much the same.

Comment: According to the dictionary, 'really' and 'so' can mean 'very', what's their subtle difference? For example, "He is very/so/really tall.

Comment: I'd add that all of those could be used to indicate sarcasm, given the right pronounciation. "so" and "really" are probably more likely to be used in that way than the other two.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion:

so < very < really < extremely

Comment: I'm not sure I agree, a lot depends on tone of voice, the situation, and what word you are intensifying. For example, for maximum effect, if I was standing in front of the Grand Canyon I may remark *It's so big.* Saying *it's really big* would have less impact, especially if I were to prolong the vowel. Sooooo big.

Comment: I agree; in fact, this was the first thing that came to mind. (+1)

Answer (score -3):

From my point of view, the difference between *so* and *very* is that:

- when we say *so*, it makes one anticipate that something follows, although it's not always the case,
- and we use *very* to clarify the sentences that we tell to somebody, it would give some lingering to the sentence.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand the difference you're trying to point out.