# What is the difference between "so" and "really"?

Tags: meaning, differences

I read an email. Then I started asking myself "What's the difference between *so* and *really*?" I couldn't answer my own question with my background knowledge.

Comment: You need to give the sentence in which you think of using one or other of those words.

Comment: Have you tried looking up the two words in a good dictionary?

Comment: Related/ Possible Duplicate: "Difference between *so*, *very*, *extremely* and *really*" https://english.stackexchange.com/q/47217/14666 ; "*Really* + [adjective] vs *So* + [adjective]" 
https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13911/99

Answer (score 2):

The intensifier *so* relates to a gradable use of an adjective whereas *really* goes with an absolute reference.

> He drives **so** fast.

This refers to "how fast" (gradable).

> He drives **really** fast (absolute).

This refers to the **fact** that he drives fast.

However, in contemporary usage, both writers and readers are accustomed to the words being interchangeably used very often, especially by the young.

Comment: A well argued description, Kris. +1

Comment: @BoldBen I agree. (+1) from me too ;)

Answer (score 0):

I might add that the adverb 'really' in '*He drives really fast*' is similar to 'very'.

And with 'so', you can also add a result, as in '....so adverb/adjective that...."

He drives so fast that I'm afraid to get in his car. 
   I'm so hungry, I could eat a horse. 
   It's so cold that I can see my breath when I exhale.